# In Regular Expression, disable double dashes

Tags: regex

I have this RegExp:

```
^(?!^(PRN|AUX|CLOCK\$|NUL|CON|COM\d|LPT\d|\..*)(\..+)?$)([a-zA-Z]|)(\:|)[^\x00-\x1f\'\?\-\*\:\"\;\|\/]+$
```

This do not allow filenames with a single dash. But I would like to do not allow only double dashes (anywhere in the filename/folder), single dash should be ok.

Thanks for any info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `[^\x00-\x1f\'\?\-\*\:\"\;\|\/]+` at the end into an expression which allows this character class, optionally followed by a dash, followed by this character class, repeated any number of times. Add an optional leading and trailing dash as well if you like. (I have added them here because it's easier than to explain :-)

```
^(?!^(PRN|AUX|CLOCK\$|NUL|CON|COM\d|LPT\d|\..*)(\..+)?$)([a-zA-Z]|)(\:|)-?[^\x00-\x1f\'\?\-\*\:\"\;\|\/]+(-[^\x00-\x1f\'\?\-\*\:\"\;\|\/]+)*-?$
```

I have required at least one non-dash character; if you want to allow a single dash, the first non-optional group could include that instead, but then the trailing context will have to look different.

I would use non-capturing groups but you're not telling which regex flavor you are using, so maybe you don't have them.